# How to find this limit if exists

Tags: limits

Let $(a_{(m,1)})_{m=1}^{m=n}$ be a sequence of real numbers, Define :-

$$ a_{(m,n+1)}=-\dfrac {a_{m,n}} {n-1}+\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum _{k=1}^n a_{k,n} $$

How to find  $\lim_{n \to \infty } a_{m,n}$ if it exists?

Comment: The notation is a little confusing for me: what do we need that second index $\;m\;$ for there? Couldn't you just say "let $\;a,b,...,a_0\;$ be $\;m\;$ real numbers, and define $\;x_{n+1}=-\dfrac{a_n}{n-1}+\ldots\;$ etc." ?

Comment: $m$ is the index, $n$ defines $n$ term of the sequence

Comment: But that is a *finite* sequence there (and thus probably not a sequence at all if we require infinity). You have $\;a_{1,1},\,\ldots,\,a_{n,1}\;$ . Just $\;n\;$ numbers, and from here on you give a recursive definition of the following terms. Am I missing something here?